# Stop Background worker in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, backgroundworker

I have WPF application.

On page I have control like "Busy Indicator" that is displayed when `PanelLoading` is `true`

```
<Grid Panel.ZIndex="1000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="3" Visibility="{Binding PanelLoading, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
        <controls:LoadingPanel x:Name="loadingPanel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    IsLoading="{Binding PanelLoading}"
                    Message="Wait"
                    SubMessage="a minute"
                               />
    </Grid>
```

On this page I also have other controls (textBoxes, comboBoxes etc.)

To ItemsSource of which I bind some values like:

```
public string SearchWord
    {
        get { return _searchWord; }
        set
        {
            _searchWord = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchWord");
            RunFilterWorker();
        }
    }
```

In above example `RunFilterWorker` will try to run every time when text is changed in textBox.

`RunFilterWorker` is a method which create BW and run it.

```
private void RunFilterWorker()
    {
        if (_filterWorker == null)
        {
            _filterWorker = CreateBackgroundWorker();//create if null (only on start)
        }
        else
        {
            if(_filterWorker.IsBusy)return; //do nothing if busy
        }

        _filterWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

        private BackgroundWorker CreateBackgroundWorker()
    {
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.DoWork += filterWorker_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += filterWorker_CompleteWork;
        return bw;
    }
```

To this BW I bind handlers on `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted`

```
        private async void filterWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        PanelLoading = true;
        var products = await FilterProducts();
        e.Result = products;
    }

    private void filterWorker_CompleteWork(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled) return;
            var products = (e.Result) as List<ProductDTO>;
            Products = products;
            PanelLoading = false;
        }
        else
        {
            LogHelper.Log(e.Error);
        }
    }
```

So when BW start his work - `PanelLoading` is set to `true` and BusyIndicator is shown. But on `Complete` nothing is happend with Indicator, it still is spinning. I am sure it isn't problem with indicator control, but with BW.

---

To @Servy:

```
private void filterWorker_CompleteWork(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        PanelLoading = false;
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled) return;
            var products = (e.Result) as List<ProductDTO>;
            Products = products;
        }
        else
        {
            LogHelper.Log(e.Error);
        }
    }
```

Doesn't help, doesn't hide Indicator.

Comment: Your Code should work as expected - have you testet your loadingPanel? I would test the following: Set PanelLoading to true, then use a DispatcherTimer to set PanelLoading back to false (completely without the bgw)

Comment: @PhilipW, using DispatcherTimer busy indicator also doesn't work as expected. So would try to find problem in control ))

Answer (score 1):

You only ever reach the line `PanelLoading = false;` if the BGW has no error and isn't cancelled.  But that's not the behavior that you want.  You want the loading panel to go away *regardless of why the BGW stopped*, so your program logic needs to reflect that.

All you need to do is move that line to the start of the completed handler.

---

You also have another unrelated problem.  You're mixing and matching `async` with BackgroundWorker, and you really shouldn't be.  BGW expects `DoWork` handlers to be *synchronous* methods.  It will mark itself as completed as soon as it has finished executing the handlers, but what you're doing is having your handler do nothing but *start* some work, and that work isn't actually being completed until long after the handler has ended.  You're therefore not actually setting the result until *after the BGW has completed*.

Since you already have a `Task` returning asynchronous method, and you're able to use `async`, just scrap using `BGW` entirely.  It's accomplishing nothing here.  Make `RunFilterWorker` `async`, have it handle any errors thrown, have it show and hide the loading panel, etc.

Comment: @demo How doesn't it help?

Comment: Well, it doesn't help to hide my busy indicator

Answer (score 0):

BGW is a very outdated technique, and as Servy correctly pointed out, it doesn't understand `async` at all. Giving it an `async DoWork` is just asking for trouble (in particular, the BGW is completing way before you expect it to).

I have a blog series that shows how [`Task.Run` is superior to BGW](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html), but in this case I'll agree with Servy that you probably don't need BGW *or* `Task.Run`. A simple `Task` should suffice:

```
Task _filterWorker;
private void RunFilterWorker()
{
  if (_filterWorker == null)
  {
    _filterWorker = FilterAsync();
  }
}

private Task FilterAsync()
{
  PanelLoading = true;
  try
  {
    Products = await FilterProducts();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    LogHelper.Log(ex);
  }
  PanelLoading = false;

  // Ensure the calling method has set _filterWorker before we clear it.
  await Task.Yield();
  _filterWorker = null;
}
```